# Compute lagged time series data

Tags: r

Let's say I have this data

```
> data <- dplyr::tibble(v = c(1:10))
> data
# A tibble: 10 × 1
       v
   <int>
 1     1
 2     2
 3     3
 4     4
 5     5
 6     6
 7     7
 8     8
 9     9
10    10
```

I now want to create an array with the shape `11x5x1`. Particularly, the rows should have the following pattern:

```
NA NA NA NA NA
NA NA NA NA 1
NA NA NA 1  2
NA NA 1  2  3
NA 1  2  3  4
1  2  3  4  5
....
```

and so on. Any ideas how to do so?
Thanks!

EDIT:

How to extend this when using a 2d timeseries?

Answer (score 1):

**1)** Place 5 NA's in front and then use `embed`.  Then reverse each row using 5:1.  No packages are used.

```
embed(c(rep(NA, 5), data$v), 5)[, 5:1]
```

giving

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 [1,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
 [2,]   NA   NA   NA   NA    1
 [3,]   NA   NA   NA    1    2
 [4,]   NA   NA    1    2    3
 [5,]   NA    1    2    3    4
 [6,]    1    2    3    4    5
 [7,]    2    3    4    5    6
 [8,]    3    4    5    6    7
 [9,]    4    5    6    7    8
[10,]    5    6    7    8    9
[11,]    6    7    8    9   10
```

**2) rollapply** An alternative is to use `rollapplyr`.

```
library(zoo)
rollapplyr(c(rep(NA, 5), data$v), 5, c)
```

Comment: thanks thats nice! How could be extend this approach in case that we have two values, meaning that array[1,1] would return another array instead?

Comment: If you are asking how to replace the NA's in (1) with some other value or values such as 0 replace NA with 0 in the code or replace `rep(NA, 5)` with some other 5-vector.

Answer (score 0):

With `sapply`:

```r
nr = 11 #Number of rows in output
nc = 5 #Number of cols in output
v = 1:10 #Initial vector

sapply(nc:1, function(x) c(rep(NA, x), v)[1:nr])

#       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#  [1,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
#  [2,]   NA   NA   NA   NA    1
#  [3,]   NA   NA   NA    1    2
#  [4,]   NA   NA    1    2    3
#  [5,]   NA    1    2    3    4
#  [6,]    1    2    3    4    5
#  [7,]    2    3    4    5    6
#  [8,]    3    4    5    6    7
#  [9,]    4    5    6    7    8
# [10,]    5    6    7    8    9
# [11,]    6    7    8    9   10
```

---

With `data.table::shift`:

```r
library(data.table)
do.call(cbind, shift(1:11, 1:6, type = 'lag'))[, 5:1]

#       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#  [1,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
#  [2,]   NA   NA   NA   NA    1
#  [3,]   NA   NA   NA    1    2
#  [4,]   NA   NA    1    2    3
#  [5,]   NA    1    2    3    4
#  [6,]    1    2    3    4    5
#  [7,]    2    3    4    5    6
#  [8,]    3    4    5    6    7
#  [9,]    4    5    6    7    8
# [10,]    5    6    7    8    9
# [11,]    6    7    8    9   10
```